# java locale getDisplayLanguage is missing a few locales

Tags: java, locale

I'm using locale.getDisplayLanguage(otherLocale) to get display several languages names in one locale.
If i'm using the following:

```
Locale loc = new Locale("he","IL");
Locale loc2 = new Locale("fr","FR");
System.out.println(loc2.getDisplayLanguage(loc));
```

It doesn't print the french language name in Hebrew.
Other locales that doesnt work are Arabic, finnish and some more.
do you have any idea? is java missing some locales translations?

Thanks,
Tal.

Answer (score 0):

> "is java missing some locales
>   translations?"

It would seem so.  In fact, I think I spotted a posting on the Sun forums site that said the same.

However, I couldn't see a current Bug in the Sun Java Bug database.  Why don't you create one?